# How can I add redux-saga to my web extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, react-redux, redux-saga, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project that creates a google chrome extension. I am trying to add redux-saga middleware for using saga debounce. However, I am getting an error that says: Argument type is not assignable of type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'. How can I fix that and How should I do that? There are not various example in the internet in web extension with middleware. Thanks for your time. Here is my code:

in background.ts

```
const middleware = [saga]
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState)
// a normal Redux store
const storeWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(store, ...middleware)
wrapStore(storeWithMiddleware, { portName: 'bla' })
```

in popup.tsx

```
const store = new Store({ portName: 'bla' })

// wait for the store to connect to the background page
store
  .ready()
  .then(() => {
    // The store implements the same interface as Redux's store
    // so you can use tools like `react-redux` no problem!
    const root = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(root)

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      root
    )
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e))
//});
export default store
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applyMiddleware` should contain only middlewares (not the store) and be passed as an argument to the createStore function:

```js
const middleware = [saga]
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware))
const storeWithMiddleware = wrapStore(store, { portName: 'bla' })
```

**Edit:**

Since you are using webext-redux, it seems you are actually mixing two ways of creating store together. You should use the `applyMiddleware` from webext-redux only if you are directly using the proxy Store from webext-redux as well. Since you are using `createStore` form redux package instead, you should also import the `applyMiddleware` function from the redux store.

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
...
```

Comment: I tried but now error changed. ''Argument of type 'Store<any,AnyAction> is not assignable to parameter of type StoreEnhancer<unknown, {}> ''

Comment: Looking at the screenshot form your other question, the whole signature of applyMiddleware looks strange. Where are you importing it from? Is it directly imported from the `redux` package? What version of redux are you using?

Comment: I import it from 'webext-redux'

Comment: oh, thats an important information. I will update my answer above.

Comment: I get the applyMiddleware from redux and create the middleware with createSagaMiddleware. Now there is no error. I wish I could :)

Comment: Update done. It is pretty much what you said. :)